# Pyside line edit background or text color change?

Tags: pyside

It's quite well documented how to make line edit widget read only, but if I want to make it even more obvious, i.e. to change the background or text color, then there is nothing to be found. Is there any way to use QColor somehow to achieve desired? Thanks

Comment: Could you post an example of code that you have or methods that you have tried? We can't really help if we don't know how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Use a [stylesheet](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) (e.g. `widget.setStyleSheet('color: red')`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Qt style-sheet** to create complex color style your own, read [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html) to see a lot of example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myQLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
myQLineEdit.setStyleSheet('''
    QLineEdit {
        border: 2px solid rgb(63, 63, 63);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
''')
myQLineEdit.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Note: **PyQt4** & **PySide** implement same.